# Web cam type video camera to iPad2 streaming over wired communication

Tags: objective-c, ios, communication, webcam, ipad-2

I want to develop an App that requires wired communication between Web cam type video camera and iPad2. Basically I will directly connect Web cam and iPad2 using cable and when I start web cam, whatever images(picture/video) captured by web cam should be displayed on iPad2.

Based on my research on this I found that iPad2 cable is only made for iPod Program so the connector is not a traditional USB port I can't do direct communication between web cam and iPad2. Am I missing anything?

We are going to use Vivotek camera and they have mentioned [here](http://www.vivotek.com/support/faq.php) that we can use safari to receive the Motion-JPEG stream. I am wondering if that could also possible on iPad 2 and is it reliable?

Further I found [Apple's MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) to develop electronic accessories that connect to iPod, iPhone, and iPad. Is there anyone out here used this already and know more about this if I can go for this?

Thanks.

Comment: why does it need to be wired?

Comment: It is going to be used in a place where Wireless(wi-fi) is not accessible!

Comment: Unfortunately I think you either go wireless or MFi.  I have seen similar questions asking about ethernet and bluetooth type attachments.

Comment: @applefreak have you found anything on this... ??

Comment: @MayankJain nope - nothing! Not sure if anything is changed since then. It's been almost two years! Have a look at MFI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can receive a motion jpeg stream in mobile Safari or in a UIWebView in a custom app.  I am not able to (yet) successfully receive a motion jpeg stream via an AVPlayer, AVPlayerItem or AVURLAsset.

Becoming a MFI authorized company is non-trivial (I tried once).  They want larger established companies that have demonstrated they have the skills and manufacturing know-how/contacts to produce quality accessories.

Curious if you can step back from your initial requirement and see if you can figure out how to do it wirelessly for at least the last step to the iPad 2.  Can go wired up to 2 feet away from the iPad and use a local private wifi network for that last 2 feet (say).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you add (use existing, or purchase) a wireless gateway.  Connect the camera to the gateway, and then connect the iPAD to the wireless network, and then browse in safari to the camera and then you can view the image.  There is no "hard wired" way to get this to work.

As for the "hard wired" portion of the question, I do not believe that is not possible without a lot of work and hardware. There is no "video in" on an ipad to make it a monitor for a camera.

Comment: This is a good answer.  You can create a small local wifi network that doesn't connect to the internet or anything other than the camera and the iPad.  We're doing this for a robotics competition for Geek's school. Get an 802.11n router/base-station for streaming speed.

Comment: @Dad I explicitly asked for wired communication so absolutely there is no scope for wireless option otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: you said it was going to be used in a place where wifi is not accessible.  The only place you can't create your own wifi network that I know of is underwater.  So, maybe you're making an underwater robot? :-)  Geek & I are.   Good luck.

Comment: Could be restrictions from whatever regulations. Many companies have sensitive stuff in secret labs where a webcam connected to wifi would cause security to freak out because OMG infinite possibilties for eavesdropping. Or it could be due to interference with other wireless equipment. Or something else.

Either way, have you considered ditching the iPad2 in favor of some other tablet which actually supports your use case?

Comment: @Jolta why even a tablet? If it is going to be wired, just use a cheap screen.

Comment: @Jolta thanks for your comment. I think we can go for other tablets if we can. We don't want to do any fency things. The main purpose is going to be monitor constantly targeted web cam view. Could you please tell me what could be other options do I have other than iPad?

Comment: Thanks @nycynik. what could be the other options other than iPad? How could I stream video to **cheap screen**?

Comment: What are your requirements for mobility? I assume that the operator would be stationary since you ask for wired connectivity. Then perhaps the best solution would not be a tablet, but a PC... Keep it simple. =)

Comment: Nah!! It's our client. They want iPad only! I can convince them using some other tablets if it's easy to use and provide little interactivity! Basically they want to package this tablet and web cam and sell it to their clients! The tablet would be at fix location but should be iPad size!