# iOS external USB camera/webcam

Tags: ios, camera, usb, webcam

How do I attach an external webcam/camera via USB to the iPhone/iPad and reach the webcam programmatically (get images from it) w/o jailbreaking?

I am pretty certain this was not possible with the former iOS APIs, but maybe with the enhanced external peripherals APIs in iOS 6 it can be done? The question asks for pointers towards how to do this.

*[Google gives tons of suggestions and apps of how to use iPads or iPhones **as a** webcam, but this question concerns how to attach a webcam to an iDevice and use it from within an app]*

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9208990/1210983

Comment: @ohaal Thanks, you are probably correct. However, this question is very concrete about the wanted solution being a standard USB webcam. In addition, the referred-to question was asked over a year ago - in the meantime, iOS 6 have come out, which as mentioned might have changed the situation.

Comment: @stolsvik have you found anything on this... ??